# UIWebView binding using ReactiveCocoa 4

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, uiwebview, reactive-cocoa-4

I'm trying my first project using reactive cocoa 4. In ViewModel  I have

```
var title = MutableProperty<String>("")
```

and in `ViewController` is binding

```
self.articleDetailView.titleLabel.rac_text <~ self.articleViewModel.title
```

I'm using for binding `UIKit` extension from Colin Eberhardt (https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/ReactiveTwitterSearch/blob/master/ReactiveTwitterSearch/Util/UIKitExtensions.swift). It works nice for `UILabel` etc.

My app using `UIWebView` so I need to bind `UIWebView`. I'm not sure how to do that. Currently in my non reactive code, I'm using method `loadHTMLString` for loading content to my webView but I have no idea how to bind `webView` with ViewModel.

Do anybody know how to bind `UIWebView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer on github. User "avalanched" (https://github.com/avalanched) send me this example:

You can bind a MutableProperty to `loadHTMLString`

if you have this in the ViewModel

```
var url : MutableProperty<NSURL>
```

you can bind it as such:

```
url.producer.map { NSURLRequest($0) }.startWithNext(webview.loadRequest)
```

Hope it helps somebody.